# Node-Gyp Rebuild failed at canvas@1.1.6 install script

Tags: canvas, node-gyp

I'll start off with saying that I have next to no experience with terminal or `node.js`

I was trying to install `paper.js` through node's `npm`and I've tried a various methods I've found.

The Visual Studio C++ was missing vcbuild.exe so I've installed the Windows SDK and that seemed to solved the problem. The node version is 0.10.33, and Python 2.7 is installed as well.

After fixing some problems with Rebuilding process I get this error:

```
 VCBUILD : error Message:  [C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pap
er\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
VCBUILD : System error : -2147154687. [C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\paper\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\paper\node_modules
\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok


> contextify@0.1.11 install C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pap
er\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

   C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\paper\node_modules\jsdom\node_m
odules\contextify>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bi
n\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xlocale(342): warning C
4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify
 /EHsc [C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\paper\node_modules\jsd
om\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
C:\Users\Decker\.node-gyp\0.10.33\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506: no
definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::Ha
ndle<T>)' [C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\paper\node_modules\
jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
C:\Users\Decker\.node-gyp\0.10.33\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506: no
definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::Ha
ndle<T>)' [C:\Users\Decker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\paper\node_modules\
jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
npm ERR! canvas@1.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "paper"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```